# How can I sort my UITableView alphabetically with NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

When the user presses "sort alphabetically", I call the following method for my table:

```
- (void) sortByName
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    NSMutableArray *items = [[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] mutableCopy];
    [items sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    int newDisplayOrder = 0;

    for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in items)
    {
        [managedObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:newDisplayOrder++ ] forKey:@"displayOrder"];
    }

    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {
       // Need code to handle error properly
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }        
}
```

But for some reason, instead of sorting alphabetically, it seems to put each item in the order it was created. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks good.

Have you set up the fetch results controller to sort according to the `displayOrder`?

In addition, you should release the items in your code...

Comment: The only two items I alloc are the NSSortDescriptor and the NSArray, both of which I release - have I missed anything else?

Comment: I've double-checked that the fetched results controller is sorting according to displayOrder. (Good suggestion though - I was sure that would be it when I read your answer). It's odd that it *does* reorder the table, but it puts everything into the order they were originally added.

Comment: Well that's odd... I deleted the app's data and put some new test data in, and it started working. Seems like the code was right all along. Perhaps it was old app data from before I changed methods that affected my displayOrder attribute?

Comment: `mutableCopy` creates a copy of the container and this one has a retainCount of `1`. You should release it after using it. Or, at least, autorelease...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects];
```

or do it in one step (doesn't need to be mutable):

```
NSArray *items = [fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

As an aside, this seems like a convoluted way of sorting a table. You are modifying displayIndex in the db to reflect the new sort order. Presumably the NSFetchRequest driving fetchedResultsController is sorting based on displayIndex.

It would be simpler and not require DB changes to simply change the fetchRequest and reconfigure the fetchedResultsController.

From NSFetchedResultsController docs:

> ### Modifying the Fetch Request
>
> You cannot
>   simply change the fetch request to
>   modify the results. If you want to
>   change the fetch request, you must:
>
> If you are using a cache, delete it
>   (using deleteCacheWithName:).
>   Typically you should not use a cache
>   if you are changing the fetch request.
>
> Change the fetch request. Invoke
>   performFetch:.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't refresh the tableview with the sorted array. I use the following method in one of my projects to sort an array of contacts based on status and name:

```
- (void)refresh {
    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
        NSSortDescriptor *descriptorStatus = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"status" ascending:NO selector:@selector(statusCompare:)] autorelease];
        NSSortDescriptor *descriptorName = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"displayName" ascending:YES] autorelease]; 
        [contactArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptorStatus, descriptorName, nil]];

        [tableView reloadData];
    } else {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refresh) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}
```

For your project you probably don't have to check if the refresh is performed on the mainthread, unless the data is retrieved from any thread other then the mainthread.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set sort descriptor while fetching the objects.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean calling a method on *items before creating it?